# SSRS BIDS 2008 Reporting Expression for years in X Axis

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

![I have a bubble chart which I would now like to add an X Axis to ranging from 1/1/10 to 1/1/13 as seen in the belowimage.

I would like to have the years along the bottom showing every 6 months, is there some way of expressing this in the interval box?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it every 6 months you put 6 in the Interval box and then change the Interval type box to Months.